# Easiest and fastest way of changing the name of your Rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

At first I thought it was as easy as changing the name of your app's folder.
But then I realized things like this:

**application.rb:**

```
module NameOfMyApp
  class Application < Rails::Application
    # Settings in config/environments/* take precedence over those specified here.
(etc...)
```

So now I'm afraid that something will brake if I start changing the name of my app in the files.

What's the easiest and fastest way of changing the name of your Rails app?

Comment: If you're on unix system you can do `find . -name "*" -print0 | xargs -0 grep -e "NAME_OF_YOUR_APP_HERE" -i` from the root of your app to see all instances of the app name

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well I would do it manually, not sure how else you could achieve it.
Here is a list of all of the files you would need to change the name in:

- config/application.rb (line 12)
- config/environment.rb (line 5)
- config/environments/development.rb (line 1)
- config/environments/production.rb (line 1)
- config/environments/test.rb (line 1)
- config/initializers/secret_token.rb (line 7)
- config/initializers/session_store.rb (line 3 and 8)
- config/routes.rb (line 1)
- config.ru
- Rakefile

Note: The line counts above are on a newly generated application, they may be different if you have changed the contents of any of these files.

Comment: Thanks! (and config.ru) EDIT: Mmm, there are apparently more files.

Comment: I got this `rake db:reset
rake aborted!
uninitialized constant Ficler` no idea where it is coming.

Comment: Oh, was `Rakefile` (I really think there should be a better way).

Comment: OK I updated the list to include both config.ru as well as Rakefile in case anyone else comes across this post.